# Providing a password for "sudo" commands with NMSSH library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ssh, sudo

I'm using a wonderful libssh wrapper for Objective-C [called NMSSH](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/NMSSH/1.2.1/index.html). I am able to make a connection, send commands, etc, but I'm having some trouble. Whenever I send an elevated command like "sudo..something", I get the following error in my response object:

```
Error: Error Domain=NMSSH Code=0 "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
" UserInfo=0x145a65e0 {command=sudo apachectl start, NSLocalizedDescription=sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
, NSLocalizedFailureReason=54}
```

How can I tell the program what the password is?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sudo -S`:

```
[session.channel execute:@"echo password | sudo -S apachectl start" error:&error];
```

From the man page:

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
>   standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be
>   followed by a newline character.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it DOES work, however, depending upon your distribution, it does not. For example, executing the following on a CentOS machine with NMSSH will return the same error "echo <password> | sudo -S ls /etc/init.d/", but it WILL work on Ubuntu out of the box. See this post for more details http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

Answer (score 0):

jonahb's solution is a nice and easy way to do it but it is very unsecure!

In case anyone wants to do it in a securer way he should edit the "Sudoers File" on the target system if possible like showen [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-this-sudo-command-inside-a-script).

Just start editing with

> sudo visudo

and past the edited version from:

> USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script

in the very end of the file.